# When fasterxml jackson 2.9 release in spring-boot?

Tags: jackson

I'm really using well `@JsonView` in jackson for district thing by authorization. But there's one small shortcoming. I have to mark `@JsonView` at every field. It's be low readablility and extension in entity class. Excepting that, I'm really using well and really appreciate that. I heard that `jackson 2.9` make the default `@JsonView` in class. But I can't use that version in even spring boot 1.5. I'm really waiting the spring boot with jackson 2.9. Could you let me know when spring boot release with jackson 2.9?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see Jackson 2.9 just had a Pre-Release #1 on the 2nd of March.
Not sure I understand how you expect to use it if it's not even released.

Comment: I expect just default `@JsonView` of class. Thanks for replying.